# How can I delete the elements of array on MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, io, output

The following code is executed but I have no idea to delete the elements of array on MATLAB.

And therefore, Array1 and Array2 are written out with the former data.

MATLAB version R2017b

```
global Array1
global Array2
filename = 'data.xlsx';
for i = 1:3
    sheet = i
    for j = (1:2)-1
        one = [1];
        two = [2];
        Array1 = [Array1; one]
        Array2 = [Array2; two]      
    end
    xlswrite(filename, Array1, sheet, 'A1');
    xlswrite(filename, Array2, sheet, 'B1');
    %here I would like to delete the elements of Array1 and Array2global 
    %Array1 = [];
    %Array2 = [];
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite `Array1` with an empty array to remove all its elements: `Array1 = []`. You would do this either at the top or the bottom of your outer loop:

```
filename = 'data.xlsx';
for sheet = 1:3
    Array1 = [];
    Array2 = [];
    for j = 0:1
        one = 1;
        two = 2;
        Array1(end+1) = one;
        Array2(end+1) = two;   
    end
    xlswrite(filename, Array1, sheet, 'A1');
    xlswrite(filename, Array2, sheet, 'B1');
end
```

I have also changed your code a bit for best practices. Some of these are recommended also by the MATLAB editor (look for the red underlines, and hover your mouse over them to get tips). I recommend you look at the differences with your code. Notably, try to avoid global variables!

But because you know how many elements the `Array1` will have in this case, it is much better (faster) to [preallocate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html), rather than assigning an empty array and then adding elements at the end. For example:

```
Array1 = zeros(N,1);
for j = 1:N
   Array1(j) = j-1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Array1(index)=[]

Just insert the index(s) of the array you wish to remove.

Comment: Every time when i is increased, I would like to reset Array1 and Array2.